# Search for tab character in a specific line of a tab delimited text file

Tags: javascript

I'm loading a tab delimited text file using the FileReader API.  Once loaded I need to find the tab location in the first line, parse out the characters preceding the tab, do some stuff with the parsed characters, then proceed to the second line, parse out the characters before the first tab in the second line, do some stuff with the parsed characters, then proceed to the third line, and so on until the end of the file.

I'm not a coder.  I could use some help on the script to perform these operations.

**Update/Edit** (as requested)**:** Specifically, taking it step by step:

- I'm able to load the tab delimited file.
- I'm able to step through the lines of the file (row 15+).
- I'm making progress on stepping through the lines in the file (row 15+).
- But I'm failing in the ability to perform a set of tasks as each line is read.

As each line is read, I want to parse out the characters in the line that are prior to the first tab character.  In the example file contents below, I want to parse out 5, then I wish to take action on the 5.  After that I want to parse out 10, then take action on the 10.  Then I want to parse out 200 and take action on the 200.  Then the script will end.

I'm assuming as each line is read that I want to call another function and send the contents of the first line to the new function.  The new function will then parse out the characters before the first tab.  Is this correct?  If not, then what should I be doing?  After that I'm assuming I should call another function, which will take the action on the parsed characters.  Is this correct (and if not, what should I be doing instead)?

If I'm correct that I should be calling another function with each line read, then how do I do so (including sending the contents of the line)?  In the code shown, I've been unsuccessful in figuring out how to do this.

Thank you,
Andrew

Example of tab delimited file:

```
5   15:00:05    2   1
10  15:00:10    2   2
200 15:03:20    2   3
```

```js
var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        var file = fileInput.files[0];
        var textType = /text.*/;
        if (file.type.match(textType)) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                // Entire file
                fileDisplayArea.innerText = reader.result;

                // Count of lines in file
                var lines2 = reader.result.split("\n").length;
                fileDisplayArea2.innerText = "The number of lines in the text file is: " + Number(lines2-1);

                // Attempt at an action per line
                var lines = reader.result.split('\n');
                for (var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++) {
                    //console.log(lines[line])
                    //with each line, how can I call another function and send along with the call the contents of the line?
                    fileDisplayArea3.innerText = lines;
                }
            }
            reader.readAsText(file);
        } else {
            fileDisplayArea.innerText = "File not supported!"
        }
    });
```

```html
Select a text file:
<input type="file" id="fileInput">
<hr />
<pre id="fileDisplayArea"></pre>
<hr />
<pre id="fileDisplayArea2"></pre>
<hr />
<pre id="fileDisplayArea3"></pre>
```

Comment: Are you looking for a tool which can do this ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: Thank you gvmani and Mike.  I have made substantial updates to the post as requested.  Hopefully it clarifies what I'm trying to accomplish and where I'm struggling.  If there is any more detail I can provide then please let me know.

Comment: gforce301, you are both mistaken & rude.  I am not a coder by trade.   I do have a "cheap" hobby website, but this has absolutely nothing to do with that project.  But I do like learning more of web technologies and this is simply a pet project.  I have no desire to have anyone write the code for me.  I desire to learn.  When I get stuck, I ask questions.  I'm quite open to just being pointed to examples and explanations, then I'll take it from there. If you don't want to help give direction, that's fine. But I'd suggest knocking off taking action on negative & incorrect assumptions of folks.

Comment: Mistaken, most likely; rude, yes but I return rudeness when rudeness is given. It is rude to not read or understand the rules of the forum where you are asking for help and to just **assume** you can post a vague generic question and expect people to help you. Self entitlement is the rudest thing of all IMO. All that being said I have given you an answer you can use to learn from now that you have posted the necessary information for someone to help you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of what you want to do. When looping each line you can get the text of that line with `lines[line]` from the `lines` array. You can then pass that text (and in my example the line number) to a function.

In my example the function is `doStuff` and it then splits the line text by `tab` character getting an array of "cells" (the values on the line that are delimited by tabs). I had the function output the values so that you could see them. You can have it do whatever you need.

```js
var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        var file = fileInput.files[0];
        var textType = /text.*/;
        if (file.type.match(textType)) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                // Entire file
                fileDisplayArea.innerText = reader.result;

                // Count of lines in file
                var lines2 = reader.result.split("\n").length;
                fileDisplayArea2.innerText = "The number of lines in the text file is: " + Number(lines2);

                // Attempt at an action per line
                var lines = reader.result.split('\n');
                for (var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++) {
                    doStuff(line, lines[line]);
                    fileDisplayArea3.innerText = lines;
                }
            }
            reader.readAsText(file);
        } else {
            fileDisplayArea.innerText = "File not supported!"
        }
    });
    
    function doStuff(lineNumber, lineText) {
        // do something with the 
      var cells = lineText.split('\t'); // '\t' is a tab character
      cellValues.innerText += "Line: " + (lineNumber + 1) + "\n";
      cells.forEach(function(value) {
          // do something with each "value" that was delimited by the "tab" characters
          // in this example add the value to cellValues
          // you can do whatever you want with the "value" here
          cellValues.innerText += '\t' + value + '\n';
      });
    }
```

```html
Select a text file:
<input type="file" id="fileInput">
<hr />
<pre id="fileDisplayArea"></pre>
<hr />
<pre id="fileDisplayArea2"></pre>
<hr />
<pre id="fileDisplayArea3"></pre>
<hr />
<pre id="cellValues"></pre>
```

### Update: Explanation of `doStuff`

The first line of the function is `var cells = lineText.split('\t');` This **does not** "replace" the tab characters with commas. What it does is create an array and store it into the `cells` variable.

In your original code the reason this line `fileDisplayArea3.innerText = lines;` is displayed with commas is because the `lines` array is transformed to a string in order to put it into `innerText`. Internally javascript calls the `toString()` method on the array which outputs it's elements **separated by commas**.

So continuing on. `cells` is now an array of the values of the line that were separated (delimited) by tab characters. We could use a `for` loop like you did to iterate the lines but I chose to use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). `forEach` will loop through (as the name suggests) each element of the array passing it's value to the function. The `value` is now available to do whatever we want with it i.e. make decisions, do math on it, etc... or (in my case) write it out to be seen.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you.  I'd gotten as far as calling the next function with the line number or the line content, but not both.  (I learned something that will be immediately useful.)  -  I kind of follow the doStuff function, but I'm wondering... Doesn't splitting on the tab character, just replace the tab with commas?  I'm not sure what that gets me.  lineText.search (for the tab) and then lineText.slice (for the number of characters return by lineText.search seems to properly parse out the leftmost characters before the tab.  Is there something I'm missing?  But again, thank you.

Comment: @Andrew I added a more detailed explanation of what is going on in `doStuff`. If you still need more, ask.

Comment: Just to follow-up; self-entitlement is assuming the negative as well.  I'm not sure where that came from.  There was no intention to be vague.  The intent was pose a problem and not presume to give the experts the method for the solution.  I most forums it's considered rude for the one asking to assume they know the best method for solving the problem, so I was simply trying to describe what I wanted to accomplish.  I believe my mistake was not being more clear that all I wanted was tips, advice, and direction, and not for someone to do it for me. For that I apologize.

Comment: Thank you (for adding more to doStuff).  I will take a look as quickly as possible (which may be awhile) and post back.  Again, thank you.

Comment: Ah! (not replacing the tab with commas)  - Rather than using the console, I have a habit of checking my variables by using an alert.  Of course that showed the array with the elements separated by commas, which caused my confusion.  Thank you for the explanation.  Now doStuff makes perfect sense, even to me.  Excellent!  Thank you again.